# Drush command to show aliases?

Tags: drush

Is there a `drush` command to show existing aliases? Some Googling didn't turn up anything.

Comment: `$ drush site-alias @self`

Comment: 'drush sa @self --full --with-db --with-optional'
will generate a template that you can append to ~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php for further use. Do not forget to change the key 'self' in the table by an unique alias name for your site.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use this in the terminal

```
drush sa
```

For example on my dev server:

```
- drush sa
@8080
@commons_3_dev
@none
@w2
```

The aliases are set in file called aliases.drushrc.php. For me this is located in /usr/local/share/drush/. Depending on how you installed Drush and on which distro you're on this may differ.

You can set up aliases in this fashion inside that file

```
$aliases['8080'] = array(
'uri'=>'server.com:8080',
'root'=>'/var/www/html_webtest2',
);

$aliases['w2'] = array(
'uri'=>'webtest2.server.com.edu',
'root'=>'/var/www/html_webtest2',
);

$aliases['commons_3_dev'] = array(
'uri'=>'yourserver.com/c3d7/',
'root'=>'/var/www/html_commons_3_dev',
);
```

For more fun, you can chain these together for server wide backups. For example, I do a big back up to all aliased sites like this

```
 drush sa | egrep "(@|default)" | egrep -v "(@none|@self) | xargs -L1 drush arb
```

Taken individually

```
 drush sa  # list site aliases
 | egrep "(@|default)"  # include default and any line containing a @ mark
 | egrep -v "(@none|@self)" # remove any lines with @none or @self 
 | xargs -L1 drush arb # with each line run drush archive-backup
```

To find path and other info, use a bit o' pipping:

```
drush sa | xargs -I {}  sh -c "echo {}; drush {} st"
```

To narrow it down to finding paths:

```
    drush sa | xargs -I {}  sh -c "echo {}; drush {} st" | egrep "(@|path)"
@8080
 Site path                     :  sites/8080.webtest2               
 File directory path           :  sites/8080.webtest2/files         
 Private file directory path   :  /var/www/drupal_private_files                   
@commons_3_dev
 Site path              :  sites/default                                          
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files                                    
@none
@w2
 Site path              :  sites/default                                          
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files
```

**update**

A bit late but I wanted to say don't forget about `drush @sites st`. I believe the `@sites` parameter will act on everything found under the sites folder. Think

```
drush @sites cron -y # runs cron on each root/sites/site
drush @sites rf
```

Comment: It would be handy also to know what filesystem path these sites map to from the `sa` command :)

Comment: Try drush @alias st (for status)

Comment: yeah, but I don't want to have to check each alias individually to see if it's the one I'm looking for. I'm dealing with a lot of aliases in a multi-site, multi-user environment. The one I want may not even exist!

Comment: Try this: drush sa | xargs -I {}  sh -c "drush {} st"

Comment: For 74 aliases that sure burns through a lot of screen lengths! :D

Comment: Get creative with pipes and grep. Sometimes the simplest bash commands strung together will give you some wonderful information.

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me you want all the details too…

Try `drush site-alias --table` or the shortcut `drush sa --table`.

Check [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) or `drush topic aliases` for further info.

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread but if anyone lands here via google - the parameter is not --table but `drush sa --format=table`.  And to save you some awk weight lifting you can use the --fields and --field-labels=0 options to keep things concise.

Comment: @DanShumaker I haven't worked in on Drupal in a few years now. Feel free to give a new answer, and I'll upvote yours.